# java.lang.nullpointerexception at android.content.contextwrapper.getsystemservice(Contextwrapper.java:386)

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a Notification Service with custom date and time, and I can't do this.
I download this code http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/ and this work fine, but when I include the code in my project don't work.

I have this code

```
package com.blundell.tut.service.task;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.blundell.tut.service.NotifyService;

/**
 * Set an alarm for the date passed into the constructor
 * When the alarm is raised it will start the NotifyService
 * 
 * This uses the android build in alarm manager *NOTE* if the phone is turned off this alarm will be cancelled
 * 
 * This will run on it's own thread.
 * 
 * @author paul.blundell
 */
public class AlarmTask implements Runnable{
    // The date selected for the alarm
    private final Calendar date;
    // The android system alarm manager
    AlarmManager am;
    // Your context to retrieve the alarm manager from
    private final Context contextt;

    public AlarmTask(Context context, Calendar date) {
        Log.v("AlarmTask", "AlarmTask");
        this.contextt = context;
        this.am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(contextt.ALARM_SERVICE);
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.v("AlarmTask", "run");
        // Request to start are service when the alarm date is upon us
        // We don't start an activity as we just want to pop up a notification into the system bar not a full activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(contextt, NotifyService.class);
        intent.putExtra(NotifyService.INTENT_NOTIFY, true);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(contextt, 0, intent, 0);

        // Sets an alarm - note this alarm will be lost if the phone is turned off and on again
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, date.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

In this line i get a error

```
this.am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(contextt.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

I send de context from this class

```
package com.blundell.tut.service;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import com.blundell.tut.service.task.AlarmTask;

public class ScheduleService extends Service {

    /**
     * Class for clients to access
     */
    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
        ScheduleService getService() {
            return ScheduleService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    // This is the object that receives interactions from clients. See
    private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();

    /**
     * Show an alarm for a certain date when the alarm is called it will pop up a notification
     */
    public void setAlarm(Calendar c) {
        // This starts a new thread to set the alarm
        // You want to push off your tasks onto a new thread to free up the UI to carry on responding
        new AlarmTask(this, c).run();
    }
}
```

and i get this error

```
java.lang.nullpointerexception 
   at android.content.contextwrapper.getsystemservice(Contextwrapper.java:386)
```

Sorry for my english :)

Comment: COuld you maybe say what you intend to do? Because your code makes no sense to me. Presumably, the context you hand over to your task is long invalid by the time it runs. That's not how it's working. Read the reference manual maybe?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is creating a notification from a date. Example: if I put an alert for tomorrow at this time, I want to remind me a notification without having to open the application

Comment: new AlarmTask.run doesn't create a thread. it just runs the method in the same thread. you need to create and start a thread to run it into another thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to issue a notification at a point in time in the future, all you need is to use `AlarmManager`, set up a `BroadcastReceiver` and start an `IntentService` from that.

Here are some code snippets:

[AlarmManager Not called next day if the app sleeps for abt 1 day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498171/alarmmanager-not-called-next-day-if-the-app-sleeps-for-abt-1-day/14498678#14498678)

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
this.am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(contextt.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

You should access ALARM_SERVICE in a static way, try this instead:

```
this.am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

Also your calling context should be accessible via `this.getBaseContext()` or `this.getApplicationContext`

i.e. you could write:

```
this.am = (AlarmManager) this.getBaseContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```